# Send myObject by TCP/IP

Tags: c#, object, send, tcp, binary-serialization

I have a problem from send myObject by TCP/IP.

My **ArchMap**

```
public class ArchMap
{
    public string DetalCode { get; set; }
    public List<Arch> Archs { get; set; }
}
```

and **Arch**

```
public class Arch
{
    public string ModulName { get; set; }
    public string PartName1 { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

I want to send this list to TcpClient but I don't know how convert my list to byte[].

I try

```
   var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
   var ms = new MemoryStream();
   bf.Serialize(ms, xarchList);
```

but I get error:

> Additional information: Typ 'Arch_Sender.Model.ArchMap' in Assembly 'ArchSender.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using `Serializable` attribute like this:

**ArchMap**

```
using using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public class ArchMap
{
    public string DetalCode { get; set; }
    public List<Arch> Archs { get; set; }
}
```

**Arch**

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public class Arch
{
    public string ModulName { get; set; }
    public string PartName1 { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx